# What does this message from HPSA RAID controller mean?

Tags: linux, raid, hp

I have two identical HP servers with hardware RAID controller.

On the RAID I have 2 SSD's as RAID1 and 3 x 1 TB SATA disks as RAID5.

On both servers I get messages like this about RAID5.

```
Jun 23 14:58:35 ve18 kernel: hpsa 0000:02:00.0: scsi 0:1:0:1: resetting logical  Direct-Access     HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   RAID-5 SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=1
Jun 23 14:58:37 ve18 kernel: hpsa 0000:02:00.0: device is ready.
Jun 23 14:58:37 ve18 kernel: hpsa 0000:02:00.0: scsi 0:1:0:1: reset logical  completed successfully Direct-Access     HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   RAID-5 SSDSmartPathCap- En- Exp=1
```

What does this message mean and should I worry?

RAID is reported as "OK":

```
# hpssacli ctrl slot=0 pd all show

Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)

   array A

      physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SATA HDD, 1 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SATA HDD, 1 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SATA HDD, 1 TB, OK)

   array B

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA SSD, 1 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SATA SSD, 1 TB, OK)
```

---

#update

```
hpssacli ctrl all show config detail

Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)
   Bus Interface: PCI
   Slot: 0
   Serial Number: 001438030E65760
   Cache Serial Number: PBKUC0BRH4I7CP
   RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Enabled
   Controller Status: OK
   Hardware Revision: B
   Firmware Version: 8.00
   Rebuild Priority: Low
   Expand Priority: Medium
   Surface Scan Delay: 15 secs
   Surface Scan Mode: Idle
   Parallel Surface Scan Supported: No
   Queue Depth: Automatic
   Monitor and Performance Delay: 60  min
   Elevator Sort: Enabled
   Degraded Performance Optimization: Disabled
   Inconsistency Repair Policy: Disabled
   Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
   Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
   Post Prompt Timeout: 0 secs
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: OK
   Cache Ratio: 10% Read / 90% Write
   Drive Write Cache: Disabled
   Total Cache Size: 1024 MB
   Total Cache Memory Available: 816 MB
   No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
   SSD Caching RAID5 WriteBack Enabled: False
   SSD Caching Version: 1
   Cache Backup Power Source: Capacitors
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
   SATA NCQ Supported: True
   Spare Activation Mode: Activate on physical drive failure (default)
   Controller Temperature (C): 51
   Cache Module Temperature (C): 36
   Capacitor Temperature  (C): 28
   Number of Ports: 2 Internal only
   Driver Name: hpsa
   Driver Version: 3.4.20
   Driver Supports HPE SSD Smart Path: True
   PCI Address (Domain:Bus:Device.Function): 0000:02:00.0
   Host Serial Number: USE426216W
   Sanitize Erase Supported: False
   Primary Boot Volume: logicaldrive 2 (600508B1001C461E4ABE42BA8B9FD70F)
   Secondary Boot Volume: logicaldrive 2 (600508B1001C461E4ABE42BA8B9FD70F)


   Port Name: 1I
         Port ID: 0
         Port Connection Number: 0
         SAS Address: 5001438030E65760
         Port Location: Internal

   Port Name: 2I
         Port ID: 1
         Port Connection Number: 1
         SAS Address: 5001438030E65764
         Port Location: Internal

   Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 1, OK
      Power Supply Status: Not Redundant
      Drive Bays: 4
      Port: 1I
      Box: 1
      Location: Internal

   Physical Drives
      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA SSD, 1 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SATA SSD, 1 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SATA HDD, 1 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SATA HDD, 1 TB, OK)


   Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 1, OK
      Power Supply Status: Not Redundant
      Drive Bays: 4
      Port: 2I
      Box: 1
      Location: Internal

   Physical Drives
      physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SATA HDD, 1 TB, OK)

   Array: A
      Interface Type: SATA
      Unused Space: 0  MB (0.0%)
      Used Space: 2.7 TB (100.0%)
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data 
      HPE SSD Smart Path: disable



      Logical Drive: 1
         Size: 1.8 TB
         Fault Tolerance: 5
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 65535
         Strip Size: 256 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 512 KB
         Status: OK
         Caching:  Enabled
         Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Completed
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001CDDB85B331A4FB8EFF79E
         Disk Name: /dev/sdb 
         Mount Points: /DATA 1.7 TB Partition Number 1
         OS Status: LOCKED
         Logical Drive Label: AEF0712F001438030E6576050DD
         Drive Type: Data
         LD Acceleration Method: Controller Cache

      physicaldrive 1I:1:3
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 3
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 1 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/4096
         Rotational Speed: 7200
         Firmware Revision: JB0OA3J0
         Serial Number: JR10006P1LJ5DF
         Model: ATA     HGST HTS721010A9
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 27
         Maximum Temperature (C): 41
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         Drive Authentication Status: OK
         Carrier Application Version: 11
         Carrier Bootloader Version: 6
         Sanitize Erase Supported: False
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

      physicaldrive 1I:1:4
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 4
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 1 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/4096
         Rotational Speed: 7200
         Firmware Revision: JB0OA3J0
         Serial Number: JR10006P2Y7MHF
         Model: ATA     HGST HTS721010A9
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 28
         Maximum Temperature (C): 36
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         Drive Authentication Status: OK
         Carrier Application Version: 11
         Carrier Bootloader Version: 6
         Sanitize Erase Supported: False
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

      physicaldrive 2I:1:5
         Port: 2I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 5
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 1 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/4096
         Rotational Speed: 7200
         Firmware Revision: JB0OA3M0
         Serial Number: JR10036P2ZZDRL
         Model: ATA     HGST HTE721010A9
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 29
         Maximum Temperature (C): 31
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         Drive Authentication Status: OK
         Carrier Application Version: 11
         Carrier Bootloader Version: 6
         Sanitize Erase Supported: False
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None


   Array: B
      Interface Type: Solid State SATA
      Unused Space: 0  MB (0.0%)
      Used Space: 1.9 TB (100.0%)
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data 
      HPE SSD Smart Path: enable



      Logical Drive: 2
         Size: 953.8 GB
         Fault Tolerance: 1
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 65535
         Strip Size: 256 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 256 KB
         Status: OK
         Caching:  Disabled
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001C461E4ABE42BA8B9FD70F
         Disk Name: /dev/sda 
         Mount Points: /boot 512 MB Partition Number 1, / 889.3 GB Partition Number 2
         OS Status: LOCKED
         Boot Volume: primary and secondary
         Logical Drive Label: 056C93E2001438030E65760E30F
         Mirror Group 1:
            physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA SSD, 1 TB, OK)
         Mirror Group 2:
            physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SATA SSD, 1 TB, OK)
         Drive Type: Data
         LD Acceleration Method: HPE SSD Smart Path

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 1
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: Solid State SATA
         Size: 1 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/512
         Firmware Revision: M5MU030
         Serial Number: 200826B63D60
         Model: ATA     MTFDDAK1T0TDL
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 35
         Maximum Temperature (C): 38
         Usage remaining: 100.00%
         Power On Hours: 0
         SSD Smart Trip Wearout: False
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         Drive Authentication Status: OK
         Carrier Application Version: 11
         Carrier Bootloader Version: 6
         Sanitize Erase Supported: True
         Unrestricted Sanitize Supported: True
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

      physicaldrive 1I:1:2
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 2
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: Solid State SATA
         Size: 1 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/512
         Firmware Revision: M5MU030
         Serial Number: 200826B5FA2C
         Model: ATA     MTFDDAK1T0TDL
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 35
         Maximum Temperature (C): 38
         Usage remaining: 100.00%
         Power On Hours: 0
         SSD Smart Trip Wearout: False
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         Drive Authentication Status: OK
         Carrier Application Version: 11
         Carrier Bootloader Version: 6
         Sanitize Erase Supported: True
         Unrestricted Sanitize Supported: True
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None


   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model SRCv8x6G) 380 
      Device Number: 380
      Firmware Version: RevB
      WWID: 5001438030E6576F
      Vendor ID: PMCSIERA
      Model: SRCv8x6G
```

Comment: Is the system hanging at the time you see those messages? Can you post the output of `hpssacli ctrl all show config detail`?

Comment: @ewwhite updated

Comment: Is the system hanging at the time you see those messages?

Comment: load average spikes. hang - may be no. the disk is for backup.

Answer (score -1):

This indicates a waiting to fail drive (or more).

The problem is there is no up-front information in the "logical reset" that would permit
pinpointing the exact drive.

You should make an thorough integrity check of all drives and some tests to find which one could cause the problems.

Replace the faulty drive, rebuild your RAID and everything should be fine. Make sure to make a backup before any replace/rebuild operations.

Comment: This seems like bad advice. I don't believe this to be the case, considering the messages are point to an hpsa [kernel driver bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199435). How would the OP thoroughly "check the integrity of the disks"?

Comment: I'd bet more likely to be a dying drive than a bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=187221